# Where's the exception message?

Tags: java, exception, maven-2

I meet a weired problem when I use maven. I execute the following code using "maven exec:java".
Obviously, it should throw a RuntimeException, but I did not see anything in console.  But if I execute it in eclipse, I can see the error message. So where does the exception gone ? Thanks

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static class MyThread extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String str = null;
            str = str.trim();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        MyThread thread = new MyThread();
        thread.start();
        System.in.read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's going into a log file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be a bug of the Maven Exec Plugin (see issues like [MEXEC-89](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MEXEC-89) or [MEXEC-80](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MEXEC-80)). Try with the version 1.2 of the plugin:

```
mvn org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.acme.Foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try adding the `-e` command line option to your mvn call, I think that solved a similar problem I had.